# Mopub Integration for Android Studio

Tags: android, integration, android-studio, mopub

As of this question I have been unable to find any resources or help on how to integrate the Mopub library project in Android Studio as everything is still only documented for Eclipse.

I used Facebook's article on integrating their library in Android Studio as a guide but still have issues.  For reference here's their article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/

Does anyone have a step-by-step process for integrating MoPub in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently found this.. https://github.com/minakov/mopub-sdk-android-aar/tree/master

Following the instructions on the repo readme page I was able to setup the mopub SDK as a dependency in my Android Studio project.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, just add the mopub sdk as a new module. You can see Details in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405809/how-to-add-mopub-ads-library-integration-with-android-studio/24402129#24402129)

Comment: how is ads going ? Admob is pretty useless.

Comment: admob is used as a fallback safety, coz basically Admob's fill rate is close to 100%, it won't show nothing when using admob . BTW, what ad network do you use?

Comment: Current is Admob , I am planning to implement Mopub as you had suggested.

Comment: you didn't solve. Its asking for "Select modules to import"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the Readme file of the project on [Github](https://github.com/minakov/mopub-sdk-android-aar/commit/a67e1f9227d6cfb7af74ff4ac73f5613a1cefb68). You can add dependency in your Android project's gradle file.

Just add the following lines in the build.gradle file.

```
    repositories {
    maven { url "http://minakov.github.io/mopub-sdk-android-aar" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.mopub.mobileads:mopub-android:+@aar'
    }
```

After this just sync your project and you are good to go.