# Android Studio won't let me import SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I was trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405809/how-to-add-mopub-ads-library-integration-with-android-studio) to import the mopub SDK into my app, however Android Studio is being difficult.

I unzipped the SDK, and went to Project Structure to select import a New Module. When I chose the unzipped folder, the Finish button is grayed out, and there is an error saying 'Select Modules to import'

I am using Android Studio version 0.8.6. [Here is a screenshot of the error menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjd64.jpg)

Comment: Does anyone know why this would happen? I really need to find a solution to this problem!

Comment: Where did you download Mopub SDK?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue so I had to install it manually.

First, unzip the downloaded file and then copy the unzipped `mopub-sdk` folder into your project directory.

Next, open your project's settings.gradle file and make sure the MoPub SDK is included as a module:

```
include ':app', ':mopub-sdk'
```

Open your app's build.gradle file (not your main project one) and add the MoPub SDK as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mopub-sdk')
}
```

These instructions are based of those found on the [mopub github](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: Copy it to my project's root directory, or does it need to be in a specific folder? I will try it in the root. Thanks for the answer, I will respond if it works.

Comment: Update: I tried this and then tried to add a banner advertisment, and I get an error saying "The following classes could not be found: -com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView" I tried building the project to no avail. The mopub sdk is in the root folder.

Comment: What steps did you try to add a banner advertisement? Did you follow this [guide](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Banner-Integration)? Does any other aspect of the sdk work?

Comment: I did not follow that guide, I just tried to directly add the objkect in XML. I followed that guide, but at step 1 when I tried to add the activities, Android Studio could not 'Resolve symbol mopub'

Comment: It seems like the library isn't recognized, which is weird because the steps I mentioned has it working for me on AS 0.8.14. The only other thing I can think of is trying File > Invalidate and Restart Caches

Comment: So I did this, and it fixes the errors you mentioned, now however, Android Studio can't resolve the symbol millenialmedia in the MillenialInterstitial and MillentialBanner

Comment: Also, "Error:(7, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist"

Comment: Assuming you have downloaded the `MoPub Android Full SDK.zip` file then you can find instructions how to integrate it [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks). Any other questions you have about this I would perhaps open a new question for.

Answer (score 4):

In eclipse, if we create a project which is **having library projects** inside our project, then

[image]

we cannot import this project as **module in Android studio**. This may be the issue

[image]

Comment: The same exact problem happened to me. Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not fault of AndroidStudio, just try archived sdk, it works

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/archive/v3.9.0.zip

from https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/releases

// sorry I don't enough reputation to post image