# mopub android studio millennialmedia unresolved

Tags: android, android-studio, mopub, millennial-media

I am trying to add MoPub adds, I use Android Studio. I tried to apply the instructions here:

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started

I couldn't apply them after title "Adding as Compiled .aar" I guess.

All seems to be fine in the project but I am getting unused import and symbol cannot be resolved errors all over in the files "MillennialInterstitial" "MillennialBanner" in folder mop-sdk/java/mobileads/util

I tried to import the jar of millennial media manually, I signed up and downloaded the resources from here:

http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-SDK/

Many thanks in advance

I guess I couldn't succeed that either. Here is a copy of my errors, if it could be of any help.

```
Error:(7, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(8, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(9, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(10, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(11, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(12, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(23, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MMAdView
Error:(122, 5) error: cannot find symbol class MMAdView
Error:(87, 54) error: cannot find symbol class RequestListener
Error:(89, 47) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(95, 45) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(101, 48) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(104, 44) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(110, 41) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(110, 58) error: cannot find symbol class MMException
Error:(116, 39) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(47, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable MMSDK
Error:(49, 33) error: cannot find symbol class MMAdView
Error:(58, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable MMRequest
Error:(61, 44) error: cannot find symbol class MMRequest
Error:(62, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable MMSDK
Error:(88, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(94, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(100, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(103, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(109, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(115, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
/Users/ugur/AndroidStudioProjects/xxx/mopub-sdk/src/main/java/com/mopub/mobileads/MillennialInterstitial.java
Error:(7, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(8, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(9, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(10, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(11, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(12, 35) error: package com.millennialmedia.android does not exist
Error:(24, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MMInterstitial
Error:(77, 60) error: cannot find symbol class RequestListener
Error:(79, 47) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(85, 45) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(90, 58) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(93, 44) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(104, 41) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(104, 58) error: cannot find symbol class MMException
Error:(118, 39) error: cannot find symbol class MMAd
Error:(41, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable MMSDK
Error:(45, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable MMRequest
Error:(48, 39) error: cannot find symbol class MMInterstitial
Error:(50, 50) error: cannot find symbol class MMRequest
Error:(78, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(84, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(90, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(92, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(103, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(107, 39) error: cannot find symbol variable MMException
Error:(117, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':mopub-sdk:compileReleaseJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

I was using the "Full SDK" of the MoPub which I did not actually need. When I used "Base SDK" instead in this link again:

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started

things worked out perfectly carrying out the steps in this post

[Android Studio won't let me import SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734779/android-studio-wont-let-me-import-sdk)

I hope I can save another person a weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found a better solution:
As the imports are not recognized, that means the class does not access to the lib of the project. So I added

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

in the dependencies session of the build.gradle of the mopub-sdk.

Below I show the whole gradle for information

```
    // This buildscript will assemble the MoPub SDK into an AAR.

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

group = 'com.mopub'

description = '''MoPub SDK'''

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 24
        versionName "3.7.0"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard.txt')
        }
    }

    // Note: You will also need a local.properties file to set the location of the SDK in the same 
    // way that the existing SDK requires, using the sdk.dir property.
    // Alternatively, you can set an environment variable called ANDROID_HOME. There is no 
    // difference between the two methods, you can use the one you prefer.
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'
}

// Don't run the Robolectric Unit Tests.
check.dependsOn.remove("test")
check.dependsOn.remove("unitTest")
check.dependsOn.remove("testDebug")
check.dependsOn.remove("unitTestDebug")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry, that project was suspended thus I could not follow this up, if I encounter the same problem I will try this one and let you know the results. Best