# Android studio error while adding mopub sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ads, mopub

I am trying to add the Mopub sdk to my android app. 
I unzipped the SDK, and went to Project Structure to select import a New Module. When I chose the unzipped folder, the Finish button is grayed out, and there is an error saying 'Select Modules to import'

I tried following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757118/5050466) but i get this error in build.gradle file in the mopub-sdk

```
Error:(8) A problem occurred evaluating project ':mopub-sdk'.
Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.robolectric'] 
Plugin with id 'org.robolectric' not found.
```

how do i get around this? Im using Android studio 1.2.2

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/archive/v3.9.0.zip

just try archived sdk, it works // sorry I don't enough reputation to post image

Comment: Now i dont get the error saying 'Select Modules to import'. The sdk imports fine but Im still getting the `Plugin with id 'org.robolectric' not found` error