# Integrating moPub into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle, mopub

I'm trying to integrate the [moPub](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk) sdk into my android studio project, but I haven't been able to get the gradle to sync properly. This question has been asked here before, but none of those solutions have worked for me. I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734779/android-studio-wont-let-me-import-sdk) instructions, but got the error messages "Plugin with id org.roboelectric not found" and "Unable to load class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling". To fix this, I modified my app's build.gradle with new classpaths:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get the error message "Error:(1, 0) Cause: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods". I've tried using version 1.0.1 of gradle but nothing changed. I'm not sure where to go from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2`? That is at least 1.5+ years old. Please use `1.3.0` and that Robolectric plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comment in that build.gradle file.

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23241888/2278598

> `<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle` is specific for app module.
>
> `<PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle` is a "Top-level build file" where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

You need to put the dependencies you are adding in the `<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, it hasn't resolved the issue. I tried placing the classpath dependencies in the module-specific build.gradles, but nothing changed. I placed them in the top-level build file based on [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/mopub-sdk-does-not-build/46397/4) help article.

Comment: I was able to get gradle to sync by putting classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.1.0' in the top level and compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5' in the app module

Comment: That's very strange. I added "classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'" to the top level gradle file and "compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'" to the app/build.gradle file, and I get the error "Error:Unable to load class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'.". Is there something else I could be missing?

Comment: Also, the error says it was "an unexpected error" and contains a log file. I've posted the log file [here](https://gist.github.com/jpbrabec/ec28b11095f949ecb851).

Comment: Hey Jman117,

You have configured Robolectric correctly in the top level gradle file. Per [this](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/23) gitHub link, you need to use a later version of gradle to build using the Groovy plugin.

I would use         

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3' `

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but unfortunately changing the gradle version like you mentioned had no effect, and I get the same exact error. This is really strange. I've even tried redownloading the mopub sdk from github instead of their website, and it hasn't changed anything. Is there more I need to do in order to change the gradle version besides changing the classpath in the main build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

You have configured Robolectric correctly in the top level gradle file.

You need to use a later version of gradle to build using the Groovy plugin. I would use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

Comment: That Robolectric plugin is deprecated and the latest Android plugin is `1.3.0`.

Comment: Yes, however, the MoPub SDK was configured with the Robolectric plugin in the version that OP is using.