# Can't get MoPub sdk into Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, mopub

I downloaded the mopub sdk and been trying to follow:

[how to add mopub ads library integration with android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405809/how-to-add-mopub-ads-library-integration-with-android-studio/24402129#24402129)

but i can't get it to import existing module. it keep saying "select modules to import" when i select the file.

If anyone used android studio 1.0.2 with mopub ads can help.
maybe a step-by-step guide would help. Can't find one for android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I followed these steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started#gradle-integration) and it worked

Do a sync once you modified the build.gradle file. Then the module should appear in your workspace.

```
Gradle Integration

Adding as Source

To include the MoPub SDK as source in your project, copy the SDK source into your project as a module. To do this on OS X and Linux, do the following:

$MY_PROJECT_DIR $ mkdir mopub-sdk
$MY_PROJECT_DIR $ cp -R $MOPUB_DIR/mopub-android-sdk/mopub-sdk mopub-sdk
Next, open your project's settings.gradle file and make sure the MoPub SDK is included as a module:

include ':app', ':mopub-sdk'
Open your project's build.gradle file and add the MoPub SDK as a dependency:

dependencies {
    compile project(':mopub-sdk')
}
```

Comment: when i did that, it says "gradel DSL method not found: 'complie ()'

Answer (score 0):

It's not fault of AndroidStudio, just try archived sdk, it works

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/archive/v3.9.0.zip

// sorry I don't enough reputation to post image

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.